# Discord command stops after attempting to read text file

Tags: c#, .net-core, discord.net

I am trying to make a discord bot that saves some data to a text file. However, when I execute the command the line that creates a stream reader stops the command.

I have tried putting the stream reader in a separate function
I have tried executing the function before the command executes and getting the data through a string

```
public class Commands : ModuleBase<SocketCommandContext>
{
    [Command("create")]
    [Summary("Creates a new group")]
    public async Task Create(IRole role)
    {
        //check for duplicates
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Data.txt"));
        //Code will not go pass this line
        Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
        await ReplyAsync("Making " + role + " into a group");
    }
}
```

I want to be able to read the file (that I will use to check for duplicates of the role) and continue with the command and have the bot say "Making role into a group" but when I execute the command, the bot doesn't say anything and the code stopped after trying to create a stream reader. However, the bot continues to run with no errors as it just stops the command from further executing.

Comment: What happens when you step through the code while debugging?

Comment: Probably file does not exist and code fails on StreamReader creation. Add try ... catch statement to handle such case.

Comment: When I debug, it goes to the StreamReader Line and just stops. However, only the command script stops and not the actual program and no logs in the console  or errors are produced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I somehow managed to fix this problem by putting the saving feature in a different class file in an asynchronous function. I found that out after creating a new bot. Still have no idea what happened.

Answer (score 0):

First off, in the System.IO namespace, you can use helper methods to easily read the entire file and create a string with its contents, all in a single programming statement. This saves you the hassle of having to write out the entire streaming process, which I think would be beneficial for your purpose.

```
string rawTextFromFile = File.ReadAllText(pathToFileAsString);
```

If you want each line as a separate index in an array of strings, there is a function for that too:

```
string[] rawLinesFromFile = File.ReadAllLines(pathToFileAsString);
```

If my solutions are not helpful to you, or you have further issues with your bot, you can use a try-catch block and you might see the problem show up in your console log. Also, this will stop the bot from crashing, because it will handle the error and continue with whatever is next in its call stack.

```
try
{
    (your code here)
}
catch(e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.message);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. However, I tried changing the formatting of the StreamReader without luck and using a try-catch would not work because my program does not crash and does not give an error.

Comment: @Jonathan As you execute it async, the error you get 'bubbles up'.
Inside your `commandhandler.cs` you have a line that says something like `await _commandService.ExecuteAsync(context, argPos, _mapper)` 
add a try catch as mentioned in this answer around that instead.

Comment: This is not a "reformatted" stream reader. This is a different way of reading entirely. It sounds like you did it wrong somehow, but without much explanation on your part the best I can do is guess what what you did based what you said. If you are trying to pass the reader as the path, if you read the intellisense it should tell you that it expects a string path ("C:/path/to/your/file"). The "File" that the method is called upon is not the variable a sream reader is stored in. It is literally the static File class in the System.IO namespace. No streamreader is needed for any of what I said.

Comment: Another note: if you are using a separate thread, you can cause an exception on that thread specifically. Try surrounding everything your bot calls with a try catch, not just the stream reader portion. I think you are confused where the error is coming from.

Comment: I've put try catches throughout my code and I still didn't find any errors that show up